# Get information from MySql Query and put it in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, mysqli

I have a table of which I must select information using a MySQLi Query and push it to the end of a PHP array.

The table is in this format:

```
table = friends

id  user1  user1_id  user2  user2_id  datemade              accepted
1   name1  1         name2  2         2015-05-27 03:24:32   1
2   name3  3         name2  2         2015-05-27 03:24:32   1
3   name3  3         name1  1         2015-05-27 03:24:32   1
4   name4  4         name2  2         2015-05-27 03:24:32   1
```

- id = an auto_incrementing number to keep track of everything
- user1 = the person's name that asks for friendship
- user1_id = that person's special unique id
- user2 = name of the person that accepts/decline's friendship
- user2_id = that person's special unique id
- datemade = the date it was made :P
- accepted = did he accept? (don't worry about this)

I want to select all users that are friends with $u.
In this example, $u's id is 1 (name is name1).
After running the query it would push it to the end of friend_array.

So if I printed this array the output would be:

```
2, 3
```

Since, id=1 is friends with id=2 and id=3

What query should I do and how would I push that to an array (I know about about array_push but I do not know how to implement it)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Have you thought about normalising your tables? Having a users and friends table separately with a foreign key relationship with user.id and friends.user_id1 and friends.user_id2?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have tried, this query 'SELECT id, user2_id FROM $friends WHERE user_id = '$user_id'' but i have no idea how to use it and what it returns.

Comment: `SELECT id, user2_id FROM` would only return the values in id and user2_id. Because you have told it to filter results to these two columns!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code. It will return the array for all user's friends.

```
$sql = "SELECT user1 AS user FROM friends UNION SELECT user2 AS user FROM friends";

$data = mysqli_query($sql);

while ($v = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `friends` where (user1 = '" . $v['user'] . "' or user2 = '" . $v['user'] . "')");
$arr = array();
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    if ($array['user1'] == $v['user']) {
        $arr[$v['user']][] = $array['user2_id'];
    } else {
        $arr[$v['user']][] = $array['user1_id'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: don't use [`mysql_*](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) extension function, it has officially deprecated  in PHP 5.5 version

Comment: I dont agree with this... it uses UNION... which means it can probably be rewritten in a better way.

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured it out!

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM friends WHERE user1_id='$log_id' AND accepted='1' OR user2_id='$log_id' AND accepted='1'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$query_count = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$friend_count = $query_count[0];
//echo($friend_count); //how many friends
if($friend_count < 1){
    echo($u." has no friends yet");
} else {
    $all_friends = array();
    $sql = "SELECT user1_id FROM friends WHERE user2_id='$log_id' AND accepted='1' ORDER BY RAND()";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($all_friends, $row["user1_id"]);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT user2_id FROM friends WHERE user1_id='$log_id' AND accepted='1' ORDER BY RAND()";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($all_friends, $row["user2_id"]);
    }
    $friendArrayCount = count($all_friends);
}
```

So it first counts how many friends you have to check if you have any, if you do not a, temp. message appearing saying no friends. If you have some friends it will run a query to check what friends you have is both columns - user1_id and user2_id. It will then finally add everything to the $all_friends array and it then counts how many friends you have.
Thank you to everyone that helped!